# Creating Site column with a custom SPFieldType

Tags: list, development, site-column, custom-field-types

i have this solution deployed on my sharepoint.

http://ilovesharepoint.codeplex.com/releases/view/44989

And i created a Site column of type Lookup with picker that is from the above solution.
Everything works good, the problem is when i try to create the field using code i cannot seem to find a way.

Right now i have the site column create but before i do any opperation on the list item i want to check if it has the column of type lookup with picker if so proceed and if not create it.

Here is what i got so far.

```
if (parentSite.Fields.TryGetFieldByStaticName("TestColumn") == null)
{

    parentSite.Fields.Add("TestColumn", !myCustomType!, true);
    parentSite.Update();
}
```

Help :'(

Comment: I found a faulty way, having the getting another field with the same type and using its FieldType attribute, but it doesnt fix the problem. I need to be able to list every FieldTypes on the site.

Comment: Are you writing this code in Feature Activated event?

Comment: No, its in a webpart.

Comment: ok can you provide some error that you are getting?

Comment: Its not an error, I cannot give the function Add a correct SPFieldType because the fieldType i want to create is deployed from another solution. Therefore it is not in the SPFieldType enum that we usually use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it took me over 1 hour fighting with this, however it isn't fully solved. 
Firstly, you are working with Lookup. These fields are really pain...

You cannot so simply add a lookup field to site, also, from my personal experience - lookups as site fields are not a good solution.
SPFieldCollection has overloaded method `Add()`, which require only SPField. However, this one didn't work correctly for me.

Retrieving custom field, easy way:
Just add reference to LookupFieldWithPicker.dll, you can find it in the wsp package.
Retrieving custom field using Reflection:

```
var assembly = Assembly.Load("iLoveSharePoint.Fields.LookupFieldWithPicker, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3443098eba475529");
var fieldType = assembly.GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(type => type.Name == "LookupFieldWithPicker");
// just use SPFieldLookup constructors, below overload nr 3
var field = Activator.CreateInstance(fieldType, web.Fields, fieldType.Name, "instanceName") as SPFieldLookup;
```

From now, you must create lookup using `AddLookup` method, because other one fails.

```
// throws: SPException: 'Use AddLookup instead'. Nice to know... 
//var name = web.Fields.Add("webLookupName", SPFieldType.Lookup, true);

var name = web.Fields.AddLookup("webLookupName", list.ID, true);
web.Update();

// redundant, just checking if field exist
var test = web.Fields.TryGetFieldByStaticName(name);

var field = new LookupFieldWithPicker(web.Fields, name);
field.StaticName = "IhaveChangedYourName";
field.Update();

// probably redudant
web.Update();
```

I finished on this. It is adding correctly lookup AND set `staticName` to "Ihave(...)" (check it with sharepoint manager). However, it is not changing the field type correctly. 
Potencial solution to resolve this problem? [Check this blog.](http://blog.beckybertram.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=5489bebf-bd8d-4a6f-995b-3a0a456796f6&ID=33&Web=316c15c2-6bc0-464f-bda1-7ba96b4ba453)
Just modify the field XML. Should work, however this is brute force.

Cheers.